# Is it possible to find rows of data that are selected by a non-rectangular brush in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, interactive

With R shiny, it is possible to select points in a scatter plot using a rectangular brush and to find their corresponding rows with the function :

```
brushedPoints(df, brush, xvar = NULL, yvar = NULL, panelvar1 = NULL, panelvar2 = NULL, allRows = FALSE)
```

a demo can be found [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-selecting-points.html)

I would like to select points and find their corresponding rows by drawing a free hand polygon. Is it possible ?

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: With the basic plot interaction you can't. But you can use [plotly](https://plot.ly/r/line-and-scatter/). It has lasso selection (and a lot of other cool stuff).

Comment: @GyD thank you very much ! Plotly is exactly what I need !